# How do I complete this three level nested query in jooq

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I have the following object relations:

```
MainObject(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var firstLvlNestedObject: FirstLvlNestedObject? = null,
)

FirstNestedObject(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var secondLvlNestedObjectList: List<SecondLvlNestedObject> = listOf(),
)

SecondLvlNestedObject(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var thirdLvlNestedObject: ThirdLvlNestedObject? = null,
)

ThirdLvlNestedObject(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String? = null, 
)
```

my select method query at the moment looks like this(*the nested objects name in generated JOOQ code is shortened for MAIN, FIRST, SECOND, THIRD*):

```
fun getById(id: Long): MainObject =
    dslContext.select(
        MAIN.ID, MAIN.NAME,
        field(
            select(
                row(
                    FIRST.ID, FIRST.NAME,
                    array(
                        select(
                            row(
                                SECOND.ID, SECOND.NAME
                                field(
                                    select(row(THIRD.fields().toMutableList()))
                                ).`as`("thirdLvlNestedObject")
                            )
                        )
                        .from(SECOND)
                        .leftJoin(THIRD).on(SECOND.THIRD_ID.eq(THIRD.ID)
                        .where(SECOND.SECOND_GROUP_ID.eq(MAIN.SECOND_GROUP_ID))
                    )
                        .convertFrom {
                            it.map { second ->
                                SecondLvlNestedObject(
                                    id = second.value1()!!,
                                    name = second.value2(),
                                    //thirdLvlNestedObject
                                )
                            }
                        }
                )
                    .mapping {firstId, firstName, secondLvlList ->
                        First(
                            firstId,
                            firstName,
                            secondLvlList
                        )
                    }
            )
                .from(FIRST)
                .where(FIRST.ID(eq(MAIN.FIRST_ID))
        ).`as`("firstLvlNestedObject")
    )
        .from(MAIN)
        .where(MAIN.ID.eq(id))
        .fetchOneInto(MainObject::class.java)
)
```

This query works fine if I comment out the thirdLvl object, but how do I include its mapping in the .convertFrom() and .mapping() methods

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @LukasEder , the main thing is that I can't figure out how to retrieve(fill the .convertFrom() and .mapping() methods for) the thirdLvlObject. The other thing is that I don't really understand why I'd require adding these methods in the first place when if I isolate select for just first-second-third level objects, it works fine without them and jooq seems to understand how to properly map these types on its own

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what the specific problem here is without spending quite some time trying to reproduce this locally. Maybe, you can try to reduce it to something much more minimal?